# partition magic

Tags: partitioning

How can I merge two partitions with Partition Magic software without losing information?

Comment: That most definitely depends on the partition types and operating system(s) involved. Please elaborate.

Comment: And, as mentioned several times over below, Partition Magic is fairly dated. Some alternatives are GParted, Paragon Partition Manager and Acronis Disk Director. If possible I would most certainly go with GParted.

Comment: Do both partitions contain data that is to be kept?

Answer (score 2):

First: Partition Magic seems to be discontinued, so it would be a good idea to find another product.

Second: There has been reports that merging two partitions with Partition Magic will lose you all the files on the second partition (the one being merged).

Third: The simplest way is to delete the second partition. Once it becomes available space, resize the first partition to include this space. This can be done with any partition editor, including the one that comes with your operating system.

Ensure only that have good backups before doing any partition work.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned PartitionMagic is a little dated so I would Look in to a [live gParted CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php). Free, easy to use and is being updated. Using the Windows built in disk management doesn't allow for much when it comes to resizing, especially in XP, and converting to [Dynamic Discs](http://www.petri.co.il/difference_between_basic_and_dynamic_disks_in_windows_xp_2000_2003.htm) could cause issues down the road if you don't understand what a [dynamic disk](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726994.aspx) is.

Answer (score 0):

I would not do that using Partition Magic, is quite obsolete, on my Win XP I could not even launch it because complained permanently about various things, you would rather go with windows embedded Disk Management, in case your partitions are on different disks, convert to dynamic disk then create spanned volumes, either way, before doing anything make sure to have backups. thanks